# MySQL - Adding a wildcard for 'any number of spaces' inside CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, concatenation

Why isn't this working?

```
    SELECT up.first_name, up.last_name
    FROM user_profiles up 
    WHERE u.activated = 1
    AND up.first_name LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%'
    OR up.last_name LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%'
    OR CONCAT(up.first_name, '%', up.last_name) LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%'
    GROUP BY up.last_name
    ORDER BY up.last_name ASC;
```

When the user enters `joe` my autocomplete returns `joe smith`.
When the user enters `smith` my autocomplete returns `joe smith`.

But when the user enters `joe smith` my autocomplete returns blank.

I want the `CONCAT` line to be able to return a result in case the user enters `first_name`  [any number of spaces in between] `last_name`.

I believe `%` will work for any number of characters, but not for **any number of spaces**. Any ideas how to fix my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are looking for a literal `%` inside a `$search_term` *(as well as the first and last names)*

**Replace this line:**

```
OR CONCAT(up.first_name, '%', up.last_name) LIKE '%" . $search_term . "%'
```

**with this line:**

```
OR ('".$search_term."'  REGEXP CONCAT(up.first_name,[[:blank:]],up.lastname) )
```

This will work provided the first_name and last_name do not contain special regex chars like `$%^[]` etc.

See; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
Note that regexp does not work with multibyte charsets, convert those to latin1 before matching.

```
OR (CONVERT('".$search_term."' USING LATIN1) 
   REGEXP CONVERT(CONCAT(up.first_name,[[:blank:]],up.lastname) USING LATIN1) )
```

Comment: thanks @johan - unfortunately it doesn't work because the single/multiple spaces may be **inside** `$search_term`-- for example `John%%%Smith` -- your line will allow for anything **between** `$search_term`, like `John Smith%%%%%` or `%%%%%John Smith` - correct me if I'm wrong! :)